# Без руля и ветрил

Tags: лексика, значение-слов

Без руля и ветрил. Что такое **ветрила** (**ветрилы**)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Без руля и без ветрил**

Из поэмы «Демон»  М. Ю. Лермонтова (1814—1841). Слова Демона, обращенные к Тамаре:

На воздушном океане
 **Без руля и без ветрил**
 Тихо плавают в тумане
 Хоры стройные светил.

**«Ветрило» в переводе с древнерусского языка «парус».**
Выражение стало крылатым благодаря опере «Демон» (первая постановка 13 января 1875 г., Петербург) Антона Рубинштейна. Впоследствии эта песнь Демона стала очень популярной в исполнении Ф. И. Шаляпина, что также добавило известности этому выражению.

Вероятно, навеяно древней мифологией, в частности известно, что вавилонско-ассирийская богиня Аллата, царица царства тьмы, разъезжала на лодке без паруса и руля.

**Иносказательно:** без ясной цели, мысли, плана, четко сформулированного намерения, «как бог на душу положит» и т. д. (иронично, неодобрительно).

◆ *Думаю, что эта партия в нынешней постперестроечной и посткоммунистической России, мчащейся **«без руля и без ветрил»,** имела бы больше шансов на успех, чем в скромной постимперской Чехословакии.* Евгений Попов, «Подлинная история «Зеленых музыкантов»», 1997 г.

*◆ Он был выдвинут политическими игроками слева и быстро поплыл **«без руля и** **без ветрил»** прямо навстречу катастрофе…* А. И. Деникин, «Очерки русской смуты. Том II. Борьба генерала Корнилова», 1922 г.

**Дополнение**
Самое удивительное, что выражение используется довольно широко и сейчас, причем в разных сферах:

**Без руля и без ветрил** ( 19.11.2016 )
*Марк Эндлин*

Знать поэзия повержена.
Мой не в моде нынче стиль.
А я пишу самоотверженно
**Без руля и без ветрил**.

«Сейчас люди существуют **без руля и без ветрил»** ( 15.11.2013 )
Константин Райкин - о «бронзовых» политиках и выпрямленных мозгах.

Кальюранд о назначении Пентус-Розиманнус ( 08.11.2014 ):
"Нельзя сказать, что министерство [ МИД ] осталось **без руля и без ветрил.** Имеется политическое руководство, и министерство претворяет в жизнь внешнюю политику эстонского правительства".

Answer (score 2):

*Без руля и ветрил*. Ветрило – парус. "Шуми, шуми, послушное ветрило" – Пушкин.